# Transform column name in row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, unpivot

I am trying to convert a column name in value of row.The result should be two columns(key,value) with column name and result. Is it possible?

```
Select Column1, Column2, Column3 From Table A
```

The result is:

```
Column1 | Column2 | Column3
John    | Monica  | Antony
```

I want to transform in:

```
KEY     | VALUE
Column1 | John
Column2 | Monica
Column3 | Antony
```

How can i do this?

Comment: Do UNION ALL's.

Comment: The keyword is `UNIVOT`

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `union all` to unpivot:

```
select 'Column1' key, column1 value from tableA
union all select 'Column2' key, column2 from tableA
union all select 'Column3' key, column3 from tableA
```

Some RDBMS have built-in functionalities to unpivot; `union all` is a cross-RDBMS solution.

Answer (score 0):

if unpivot support your dbms then you can do

```
select u.key,u.VALUE
from table s
unpivot
(
  VALUE
  for Key in (Column1, Column2, Column3)
) u
```

Comment: When y try to do it i have: The type of column Column2 conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list.

Comment: @btgf what is the data type of your 3 columns